# Different class files for same dependency when used in different projects

Tags: spring, maven, gradle

I was given a spring project with gradle as the build tool. Since I'm familiar with maven I tried to change the project build tool to maven. I defined the dependencies in pom.xml like it was in build.gradle using the same group id, artifact id and version. However with the maven version of the project there is an error with one dependency, comparing both dependencies I found that the class files are different, I've searched and found nothing close to my problem.

In build.gradle

`compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.10.4.RELEASE'`

In pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The difference in code is found in `CrudRepository.class`

In the project with pom.xml this is the class

```
/*
 * Copyright 2008-2017 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.springframework.data.repository;

import java.util.Optional;

/**
 * Interface for generic CRUD operations on a repository for a specific type.
 * 
 * @author Oliver Gierke
 * @author Eberhard Wolff
 */
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID> extends Repository<T, ID> {

/**
 * Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the
 * entity instance completely.
 * 
 * @param entity must not be {@literal null}.
 * @return the saved entity will never be {@literal null}.
 */
<S extends T> S save(S entity);

/**
 * Saves all given entities.
 * 
 * @param entities must not be {@literal null}.
 * @return the saved entities will never be {@literal null}.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException in case the given entity is {@literal null}.
 */
<S extends T> Iterable<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities);

/**
 * Retrieves an entity by its id.
 * 
 * @param id must not be {@literal null}.
 * @return the entity with the given id or {@literal Optional#empty()} if none found
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code id} is {@literal null}.
 */
Optional<T> findById(ID id);

/**
 * Returns whether an entity with the given id exists.
 * 
 * @param id must not be {@literal null}.
 * @return {@literal true} if an entity with the given id exists, {@literal false} otherwise.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code id} is {@literal null}.
 */
boolean existsById(ID id);

/**
 * Returns all instances of the type.
 * 
 * @return all entities
 */
Iterable<T> findAll();

/**
 * Returns all instances of the type with the given IDs.
 * 
 * @param ids
 * @return
 */
Iterable<T> findAllById(Iterable<ID> ids);

/**
 * Returns the number of entities available.
 * 
 * @return the number of entities
 */
long count();

/**
 * Deletes the entity with the given id.
 * 
 * @param id must not be {@literal null}.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException in case the given {@code id} is {@literal null}
 */
void deleteById(ID id);

/**
 * Deletes a given entity.
 * 
 * @param entity
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException in case the given entity is {@literal null}.
 */
void delete(T entity);

/**
 * Deletes the given entities.
 * 
 * @param entities
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException in case the given {@link Iterable} is {@literal null}.
 */
void deleteAll(Iterable<? extends T> entities);

/**
 * Deletes all entities managed by the repository.
 */
void deleteAll();
}
```

In the project with build.gradle this is the class

```
/*
 * Copyright 2008-2011 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.springframework.data.repository;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Interface for generic CRUD operations on a repository for a specific type.
 * 
 * @author Oliver Gierke
 * @author Eberhard Wolff
 */
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {

    /**
     * Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the
     * entity instance completely.
     * 
     * @param entity
     * @return the saved entity
     */
    <S extends T> S save(S entity);

    /**
     * Saves all given entities.
     * 
     * @param entities
     * @return the saved entities
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException in case the given entity is {@literal null}.
     */
    <S extends T> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> entities);

    /**
     * Retrieves an entity by its id.
     * 
     * @param id must not be {@literal null}.
     * @return the entity with the given id or {@literal null} if none found
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code id} is {@literal null}
     */
    T findOne(ID id);

    /**
     * Returns whether an entity with the given id exists.
     * 
     * @param id must not be {@literal null}.
     * @return true if an entity with the given id exists, {@literal false} otherwise
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code id} is {@literal null}
     */
    boolean exists(ID id);

    /**
     * Returns all instances of the type.
     * 
     * @return all entities
     */
    Iterable<T> findAll();

    /**
     * Returns all instances of the type with the given IDs.
     * 
     * @param ids
     * @return
     */
    Iterable<T> findAll(Iterable<ID> ids);

    /**
     * Returns the number of entities available.
     * 
     * @return the number of entities
     */
    long count();

    /**
     * Deletes the entity with the given id.
     * 
     * @param id must not be {@literal null}.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException in case the given {@code id} is {@literal null}
     */
    void delete(ID id);

    /**
     * Deletes a given entity.
     * 
     * @param entity
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException in case the given entity is {@literal null}.
     */
    void delete(T entity);

    /**
     * Deletes the given entities.
     * 
     * @param entities
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException in case the given {@link Iterable} is {@literal null}.
     */
    void delete(Iterable<? extends T> entities);

    /**
     * Deletes all entities managed by the repository.
     */
    void deleteAll();
}`
```

They differ in their import and there is a method `findOne(Id id)` in the project with gradle but its missing in the project with maven. I can't understand what I've done wrong.

Comment: So, you're willing to put all the effort in to convert the build you don't quite understand from gradle to maven rather than put a little bit of effort into learning gradle? You should give it a try, you'll probably like it

Comment: I'd love to wean the world off it's maven addiction and migrate many projects from maven to gradle. Then we have people like you trying to undo some of the good work. What a shame

Comment: i tried, project does not run at all with the current configuration with gradle, this was my last resort, but how can the above problem occur at all ?

Answer (score 1):

Gradle and maven have different conflict resolution strategies when there's more than one version of an artifact in the dependency graph

- Maven has a "nearest definition wins" strategy where the version which is defined in a transitive pom which is "nearest" to your project wins. In my opinion this is a stupid strategy. You can force a version by explicitly stating the required version in your project's pom.xml since that is "nearest"
- Gradle by default will pick the highest version number. The resolution strategy is fully configurable in Gradle (eg you can force a specific version)

For maven, type

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

For gradle type

```
gradle dependencies
```

If you compare the results you should see the difference

Comment: Not quite sure if I got what you're saying, but I believe I have defined version explicitly in the pom file, haven't I ? I see there are difference in the tree but the main dependency still shows the same version.

Comment: The differences between the trees are why you are seeing different versions of that particular class. The version you define in your POM or build script is not always the version you actually get. Does that make sense?